# Are the original Starcraft 2 WoL and HotS DVDs still useful for installing the game?

Tags: diablo-iii, starcraft-2, battle.net

It's been many years since those games came out, and in preparation for Legacy of the Void I'd like to replay the whole series. However, the Battle.net application is quoting me a ~20 GB download which is quite a lot for my internet connection. I'm also aware that the games have been heavily patched since their original release. If I can find copies, would using the original installation media reduce this number significantly?

This question would also apply to Diablo 3 and Reaper of Souls as its a similar situation.

Comment: It should reduce the amount of data downloaded as the base files would be installed with the Dvd instead of being download but, on the other hand, patching the files might still require you to download over 10Gb. Without testing, it's hard to tell if the difference is important or not. Also, IIRC, the patching will not be done in one pass, you'll have to download a patch, install, download the next. It might be faster to download the 20Gb if you don't have a data limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will reduce the amount of data that you will be required to download.

From Blizzard Support Rep:

> [the disk] contains a pretty up to date client [1.5.x (stated in another comment)] which will take you some way but as with all of our games, StarCraft II is constantly evolving and it will reach a point where downloading the client on a broadband Internet connection will be quicker and simpler than installing from a disc and then patching up with the latest data.

By how much though is a very difficult to answer question without actual testing of the build on the disk as well as the current production release available to download. It would depend on many things such as how the patching system works and how much data has been changed since the DVD version.

As a guess I will say that it may save up to 4gb.

A possible solution for you may be to download and install the game somewhere else, perhaps at work or school (if they let you) or a net cafe, and then copy the install files onto an external harddrive and then bring it home and copy it onto your home computer. This will likely mean you will not have to download any thing else.

Answer (score 4):

As far as *Diablo 3* goes, there's virtually no benefit to using a physical installation media. It has the tiny Battle.net launcher on it, and that's it.

However, if your connection sucks as much as mine does, and you don't want to spend a week downloading D3 (or *months*, if you have a transfer cap!), I recommend finding someone who's already installed the game and copying the game's installation folder to your computer using a USB stick or something similar.

If you point the Battle.net launcher to your friend's installation folder on your computer (using the `Locate` link next to the big `Install` button), the launcher will work out what it can use and what it needs to download.

This even works cross-platform: you can copy the installation folder from your friend's Mac and put it on your Windows PC (or vice-versa), and nearly all of the D3 game data will be used as is! The launcher will just download the platform-specific executable. This is, to my mind, the best way to avoid heavy downloads. If you don't know anyone who already has D3 installed, I'd follow @Aequitas's advice and download the game from a PC that has better Internet than you have at home.

Comment: Great tip with the copying of an installed version!

Comment: It's surprisingly flexible :)

Answer (score 3):

If you use the Battle.net launcher, you don't really need to worry about the internet connection.

If your download fails or is interrupted during the download process, the Battle.net launcher will pick up from where it left off.

Technically, using the CD's to download the game would obviously help with your internet connection issues. But I still **highly** recommend the Battle.net launcher.

Comment: The way I read it OP wasn't concerned about drops out or the like, they were concerned about having to download 20GB, which I think poses two issues to some people; 1. the chance of "going over" their quota for the month, causing limited speed and/or excess fees. and 2. A slow connection may mean 20GB would take several weeks to download

Comment: Aequitas has interpreted my question correctly. I'm asking which way will involve the least amount of data being downloaded. As Jonathan Drapeau has pointed out, it's not immediately obvious.

Comment: Oh no problem. I'm glad you have your answer. StarCraft and diablo are two amazing games! I'm just happy you are going to enjoy them